# Altair Map, Is it possible to add a basemap?

Tags: python, mapping, matplotlib-basemap, altair

I am working on a very basic map using *Altair*, using vector data (point locations). General visualization capabilities are great, but I can not find out if it is possible to use a basemap with my map.

Something similar to `mpl_toolkits.basemap` maybe?

Comment: I came across this: https://github.com/nyurik/leaflet-vega. If anyone has the same problem, it seems link the problem is easy to solve, not on altair but vega.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as of the current version (Altair 4.0), there is no functionality to add basemaps to geographic charts in Altair. The relevant Vega-Lite feature request can be found here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5758

Comment: Adding for documentation / experimentation purposes that if we had a working Matplotlib renderer for altair then adding basemap would have been really easy using Contextily - https://geopandas.org/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html#sphx-glr-gallery-plotting-basemap-background-py
All it needs is the axis object of Matplotlib.